# get value of an element by parse xml in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing, tbxml

I'm using TBXML to parse xml. But I have a problem.
This is my xml file

```
<i va="00:13:025">*4</i>
<i va="00:18:915">*3</i>
<i va="00:19:995">*2</i>
<i va="00:21:075">*1</i>
```

I used the command

```
TBXMLElement *lyric = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"i" parentElement:param];
```

to get value "*4". How can I get value on va=""? Do you have any ideas or some examples to slove this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that values by using NSXMLParser..

```
NSXMLParser *xmlstr = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] ;
xmlstr.delegate = self;
[xmlstr parse];
```

And use this delegate method.

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
     NSLog(@"%@",[attributeDict description]);
}
```

This attributeDict will gives you the attribute in that started tag.